# Having issues sending scope to the template in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, silex

MY issue is this:

When I request the data from the server this sent the data correctly but in `LoginController` after doing the validation I'm trying to populate the user's username and email but those variables are not being printed in the template. However if I just send those variables in a simple JSON such as `$scope.details = [{ 'username':'Karman', 'username':'karman@mail.com'}];` it's working fine, what am I doing wrong? Is there some issue with ng-repeat directive?

Thanks in advance to whom can help me out with this issue.....

ps: I'm using sillex and ng-resource just in case

```
    <body ng-controller="LoginController">   
        <div class="col-xs-3 details-user">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img src="web/img/avatar.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="detail in details">
                        {{detail.username}} -- {{detail.email}}
                    </li>
                </ul>          
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
    function LoginController($scope, Login) {

       var currentResource;

       $scope.login = function () {

           Login.query({email: $scope.email}, function success(data){
                $scope.details = data;
               //$scope.details = [{ 'username':'Karman', 'username':'karman@mail.com'}];
           });
       }
    }
```

Form:

```
<!-- Main DIV -->
<div id="login" class="login-main">
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <div class="form-header">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-main">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input ng-model="email" type="text" class="input-large" placeholder="Tu email aqui..." required>
                    <input ng-model="password" type="password" class="input-large" placeholder="Tu password aqui..." required>
                </div>
                <button ng-click="login()" ng-show='addMode' class="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>
            </form><!-- end form -->
        </div><!-- end div form-main -->
        <div class="form-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
                    <a href="" id="forgot_from">Forgot password?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    <a href="" id="signup_from">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you verified what `data` is in the success call -- is it exactly what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for answer me. Well, if I print data by console this is the result: -- console.log(data)

f {username: "Karman", email: "karman@mail.com", $promise: Object, $resolved: true…}
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
email: "karman@mail.com"
username: "Karman"
__proto__: f

Comment: Then data contains the fields that I requested...

Comment: so does that mean `data.f` is actually the data you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks man for answering but data.f does not work, I mean dat is fine data.f does not make sense but just for the record I printed data.f and the result is undefined, i don't know what I am missing

Comment: You have to trigger the call for login method (either by explicit call on LoginController or by attaching it to a button in the template and click on that button). Right now, $scope.login() is never called, and consequently, it won't be executed.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel but as you can see I added the form and checking that I am calling login() function, :(, is that what you mean?

Comment: Is it necessary to use ngRepeat? could you just do `$scope.details = data[0]`? Also, if `data` is coming from a response with `$http`, `data` might be an object with a nested _data_: `data.data`.

Comment: @jacob Thanks for answering me but both suggestions did not work :(

Comment: please post a working sample (jsfiddle , plnkr, etc)